# Cordova build error on google-service/firebase vs gradle or java

Tags: java, android, android-studio, cordova, gradle

I'm using Cordova and when I run `cordova build android` it's throwing an error. Like several months ago, it was no problem building the APK. I think Java did auto update, causing an issue?

I suppose it has something to do with the `com.google.gms:google-service` and maybe the gradle? I've no clue.

This is the full terminal output:

```
% cordova build android
[Gradle Properties] Detected Gradle property "android.useAndroidX" with the value of "true", Cordova's recommended value is "false"
[Gradle Properties] Detected Gradle property "android.enableJetifier" with the value of "true", Cordova's recommended value is "false"
cordova-plugin-firebasex: Preparing Firebase on Android
Checking Java JDK and Android SDK versions
ANDROID_SDK_ROOT=undefined (recommended setting)
ANDROID_HOME=undefined (DEPRECATED)
Using Android SDK: /Users/<user>/Library/Android/sdk
Subproject Path: CordovaLib
Subproject Path: app

> Configure project :app
Adding classpath: com.google.gms:google-services:4.2.0
registerResGeneratingTask is deprecated, use registerGeneratedResFolders(FileCollection)
registerResGeneratingTask is deprecated, use registerGeneratedResFolders(FileCollection)

> Task :app:processDebugGoogleServices
Parsing json file: /Users/<user>/Sites/cordova/<projectname>/platforms/android/app/google-services.json

> Task :CordovaLib:compileDebugJavaWithJavac FAILED

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':CordovaLib:compileDebugJavaWithJavac'.
> java.lang.NullPointerException (no error message)

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

Deprecated Gradle features were used in this build, making it incompatible with Gradle 7.0.
Use '--warning-mode all' to show the individual deprecation warnings.
See https://docs.gradle.org/6.5/userguide/command_line_interface.html#sec:command_line_warnings

BUILD FAILED in 1s
21 actionable tasks: 5 executed, 16 up-to-date
Command failed with exit code 1: /Users/<user>/Sites/cordova/<project>/platforms/android/gradlew cdvBuildDebug -b /Users/<user>/Sites/cordova/<project>/platforms/android/build.gradle
```

**Versions**

```
javac -version
javac 1.8.0_292
```

```
------------------------------------------------------------
Gradle 6.9.1
------------------------------------------------------------

Build time:   2021-08-20 11:15:18 UTC
Revision:     f0ddb54aaae0e44f0a7209c3c0274d506ea742a0

Kotlin:       1.4.20
Groovy:       2.5.12
Ant:          Apache Ant(TM) version 1.10.9 compiled on September 27 2020
JVM:          11.0.12 (Homebrew 11.0.12+0)
OS:           Mac OS X 11.3.1 x86_64
```

Thanks for any advice in advance!

Answer (score 1):

Okay.. So I solved this part, but wanted to keep this post here for others who might run into the same problem.

**Gradle**

`brew uninstall gradle@6` (because I manually installed this version)

`brew install gradle` (which is installing version 7.1.1 currently)

**Cordova**

`cordova platform remove android` (I was on 9)

`cordova platform add android@10.1.0`